# How do I delete my account?

Tags: discussion

This is an unhelpful and unfriendly forum. Every question gets closed, it's nothing but nit picking, and you will close a question without actually address the content of it. BYE! PS Visit reddit for actual helpful answers!

Comment: If you want to delete your account, there is a help page for that: "[How do I delete my account?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)"

Comment: @TamirEvan very helpful answer! :)